# Open source or free spyware / malware detection?

Tags: security, malware, spyware, malware-detection

I'm building a system to control where my company's ads are placed. Amongst our concerns are potentially malicious code on the target page. Is there any library / database / system that can detect this content and is either open source or free?

~downer

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could look at Google's Safe Browsing API:

Single search:

http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=www.example.com

Signup for API key:

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/key_signup.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just want to make sure that your company's ad does not appear on the pages that are serving malware/spyware.

As mentioned earlier, google api can be used for querying Safebrowsing database. Also, if the marketing company who is going to be running your campaign can provide you the the list of target pages, you can additionally use McAfee Site advisor. Two checks are better than one.

Site Advisor: http://www.siteadvisor.com/websecurity/index.html